# Solaris 10: BIND 9 Chroot Service fails to start with SVCADM but works when run manually from root

Tags: solaris, bind, service

I recently upgraded with Solaris patches and after the reboot my Bind Named services go into maintenance mode.

```
bash-3.2# svcs -xv
svc:/network/dns/server:chroot (?)
 State: maintenance since Thu Nov 01 00:22:19 2012
Reason: Start method failed repeatedly, last exited with status 1.
   See: http://sun.com/msg/SMF-8000-KS
   See: man -M /usr/man -s 1M named
   See: /var/svc/log/network-dns-server:chroot.log
Impact: This service is not running.
```

**Output from var/svc/log/network-dns-server:chroot.log below**

> [ Nov  1 00:22:19 Executing start method ("/lib/svc/method/dns-server
>   start chroot") ] dns-server: Executing: named  -t
>   /var/named/chroot/named -c /etc/named.conf /lib/svc/method/dns-server:
>   named: cannot execute dns-server : start failed! Check syslog for
>   further information. [ Nov  1 00:22:19 Method "start" exited with
>   status 1 ]

As stated I can run `named  -t /var/named/chroot/named -c /etc/named.conf` manually from root and the named process starts and DNS works.

I assume this has something to do with permissions/file ownership or something like that. I have tried changing (chown/chgrp)the /var/named/chroot/named directory to root root and named root. I also did the same with the /var/named/chroot/named/named binary. I also tried the same types of things with the /etc/named.conf file. So far no luck.

Any suggestions on how to figure this out would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, but I bet '`named`' is in *your* `$PATH` but not the global `$PATH`.
I would recommend either;

**a)** Determine the path to `named` and ensure the path is in `/etc/profile`

**b)** Find the spot(s) in the `/lib/svc/method/dns-server` script and prefix the path to `named`